# nodejs express doesn't render html page with ect templating engine when it runs as a docker daemon

Tags: node.js, express, docker

am trying to run a node js application that renders HTML pages on ECT templating engine on Docker, the case is that it works just fine once am interacting directly with the running container as below command and run node inside it.

```
docker run -p 80:5000 -it abdullahshahin/admin-panel bash
```

but when I run it as a daemon, express shows below error

> Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/views"

below is the declaration of ect

```
var ectRenderer = ECT({ watch: true, root:'/var/njs/html/views', ext : '.ect' });
```

also, I tried this

`root: __dirname + '/views' and this root:'./views'`, nothing helped.

below is the main app file code, am using MVC on this one

```
// DECLARE VARIABLES
var express = require('express');
var instance = express();
var parser = require('body-parser');
instance.use(parser({strict:false}));
var commander = require('commander');
var ECT = require('ect');
var ectRenderer = ECT({ watch: true, root: __dirname + '/views', ext : '.ect' });

    // PROMPTE USERS TO ENTER PORT
    commander.option('-p, --port <n>', 'Port to run server on',parseInt).parse(process.argv);
    if(!commander.port)
    {
        console.log("Please provide a port number");
        process.exit(1);
    }

    // EXPRESS USES
    instance.set('view engine', 'ect');
    instance.engine('ect', ectRenderer.render);
    // EXPRESS TO USE ROUTES
    require("./routes/routes.js")(instance);
    //instance.use(parser);
    // EXPRESS TO USE PROMPTED PORT
    instance.listen(commander.port);
```

below is the Dockerfile content

```
FROM        ubuntu

RUN         apt-get update

RUN         apt-get --yes install software-properties-common

RUN         apt-add-repository -y ppa:chris-lea/node.js

RUN         apt-get update

RUN         apt-get --yes install nodejs

COPY . /var/njs/html

RUN cd /var/njs/html; npm install

EXPOSE      1234

CMD node /var/njs/html/app.js -p 1234
```

has anyone had any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Can you also post the Dockerfile content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found it, I mentioned the working directory with the daemon option when run the container as below

```
docker run -p 80:1234 -w="/var/njs/html" -d abdullahshahin/admin-panel
```

https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#env-environment-variables